# drupal webform confirmation message anonymous user

Tags: drupal, webforms

I am relatively new to drupal, I am using webform 7.4.17 with drupal 7.59, I am displaying webform as block on page, with no-redirect. I need to display confirmation message for successful submission.I am getting that for authenticated users. but for anonymous users, no confirmation message appears, after successful submission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can helps :

https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2008-05-29/handling-drupal_set_message-for-anonymous-users

> Somehow the anonymous user was deleted from the database. So check to
>   see if you have a uid of 0 still there. If it isn't there, put it
>   back. That cleared up this issue for me. Here is the sql to do it. The
>   question here is, where did that user go, how did it get deleted?
>
> INSERT INTO users (uid, name, mail) VALUES ('0', '', ''); INSERT INTO
>   users_roles (uid, rid) VALUES (0, 1);